# Custom UISlider

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

How to customize UISlider?(change style,background,...)

Comment: Gonna have to be *way* more descriptive for this question to even have a chance...

Answer (score 11):

You can go through [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) tutorial for customizing the controls.

For customizing UISlider,use this piece of code from this tutorial.

```
UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum.png"] 
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *maxImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum.png"] 
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"];

     [[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage 
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:minImage 
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage 
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 8):

Read the documentation: [`UISlider` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Have a close look at the following methods:

> Changing the Slider’s Appearance

```
setMinimumTrackImage:forState:
setMaximumTrackImage:forState:
setThumbImage:forState:
```

For background have a look at UIView documentation.

Answer (score 5):

IF you want some example code I could recommend you to look at Apple's example code project [UICatalog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html). This project gives you some basic knowledge about many of the UI elements. In the example they have a custom slider with different colors to the default UISlider.