# UISlider in thermometer-ios

Tags: ios7, uiimageview, uislider

I need to set the UISlider in thermometer. Here am setting the slider left track image in red color and right track image in white color and a thermometer image is available.when the user tap on the slider,value increases and it gives the look of thermometer.How to set the slider inside that image?I have tried in many ways but UISlider is hiding behind the thermometer image. And also please tell me the image size for thumb,left track and right track images.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ptsd-coach/id430646302?mt=8

Please refer the fourth screenshot in the above link.I want to do the exact.

Please help.

Comment: I think you want custom UISlider This link help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748473/custom-uislider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748473/custom-uislider) And for Vertical slider [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377030/how-to-put-uislider-vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377030/how-to-put-uislider-vertical)

Comment: DOne with vertical slider.I want to place the slider at the top of imageview.please help